# Ошибка доступа к API ВКонтакте: Open api access error

Tags: javascript, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, sdk

Почему в консоли пишет

> openapi.js:563 Open api access error

[Вот мой код](http://plnkr.co/edit/AihG6swFrzqBQatK9NlZ?p=preview). Почему раньше работало, а сейчас нет?

Я пробовал ещё приложение 2903251, PopUp появляется, но в консоли всё равно ошибка.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="http://vk.com/js/api/openapi.js"></script>

<script language='javascript'>
 VK.init({
    apiId: 5746407
  });

  let cb = response => {
    console.log(response);
    if (response.session) {
      console.log('авторизация прошла успешно');
    } else {
      console.log('ошибка авторизации');
    }
  };

  VK.Auth.login(cb);

 //VK.Auth.revokeGrants()
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это потому, что у вас в настройках приложения в качестве адреса сайта указано `http://localhost` или вообще ничего не указано. Адрес в настройках приложения должен совпадать с тем, откуда делается запрос, иначе авторизация не сработает.

Также обращайтесь ко ВКонтакте **только** по протоколу HTTPS.

Comment: А почему в консоле не выводит значение переменной userData?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="http://vk.com/js/api/openapi.js"></script>

<div class="container">
 <h1 id="headerInfo"></h1>
</div>
 <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/n56ZycWqpbD2QSueWcyS?p=catalogue